# Minecraft Forge textures missing as of update 1.7.10

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

So I've been modding Minecraft for about a week now and its been going smooth, but I've had texture problems, after upgrading forge from 1.7.2 to 1.7.10.

Modded items, modded blocks, as well as vanilla ones variants either come up as black squares, blue/static like, or transparent.

I've disabled every mod, and re-launched Minecraft, but this still happens within Forge.

[image: texture problems]

Why is the new version of forge doing this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about tech support for modded Minecraft.  We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Comment: Voting to leave open, as per [What is technical support, exactly?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11015/what-exactly-is-technical-support). We are not being asked to solve a modded minecraft crash, here, which is what the original ban was on, and what the only agreed upon meta defines our ban on. Furthermore, asker has put in the effort to localise the problem to Forge.

Comment: Did you just upgrade forge from 1.7.2 to 1.7.10? Leaving the mods as they were? If so, this would be the problem as not even the two vanilla Minecraft versions are compatible. Iirc you couldn't connect to a 1.7.2 server from 1.7.10 and vice-versa. You would need to get the mod versions that are specific to Minecraft 1.7.10, and I remember a lot of mods went either 1.7.2 or 1.7.10, and very few had versions for both before they started working towards upgrading their mods to Minecraft 1.8 and up.